# The thread is queued disorderly when using netcore 3.1 in debug mode in VS

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, .net-core, semaphore

### Test environment

- .netcore 3.1(.netcore 2.x not tested)

  - **Start new debug instance in vs studio: Not expected ❌.**
  - Debug Build:  no problem ✔.
  - Release Build: no problem ✔.
- .NET Framework 4.7.1(other version not tested).

  - Start new debug instance in vs studio: no problem ✔.
  - Debug Build:  no problem ✔.
  - Release Build: no problem ✔.

### The reproducible code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;

namespace SignalTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                new Thread(new ThreadStart(new Worker($"c{i % 3}", $"name{i}").Start)).Start();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }


    class Worker
    {
        public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Semaphore> Semaphores  = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Semaphore>();

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }

        public int Count { get; private set; }

        public Worker(string code, string name)
        {
            Code = code;
            Name = name;

            Semaphores.TryAdd(Code, new Semaphore(1, 1));
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    WriteLog($"[{Code}][{Name}] Wait.");

                    Semaphores[Code].WaitOne();
                    WriteLog($"[{Code}][{Name}] Begin.");

                    WriteLog($"[{Code}][{Name}] Working => {++Count}!!!");
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                finally
                {
                    WriteLog($"[{Code}][{Name}] Release.");
                    Semaphores[Code].Release();
                }
            }
        }

        public void WriteLog(string msg)
        {
            if (Code == "c1")
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

The desired output should be all of the `c1-coded` threads printed 1, then print 2, then 3..., but in dotnetcore 3.1 (VS Debug instance, Debug > Start New Instance), the result may not be what you want, is that a bug?

One of the unwelcome output fragment may be:

```
[c1][name1] Working => 4!!!
[c1][name1] Release.
[c1][name1] Wait.
[c1][name4] Begin.
[c1][name4] Working => 4!!!
[c1][name4] Release.
[c1][name7] Begin.
[c1][name7] Working => 4!!!
[c1][name4] Wait.
[c1][name7] Release.
[c1][name7] Wait.
[c1][name10] Begin.
[c1][name10] Working => 2!!!
[c1][name10] Release.
[c1][name10] Wait.
[c1][name13] Begin.
[c1][name13] Working => 1!!!
[c1][name13] Release.
[c1][name13] Wait.
[c1][name16] Begin.
[c1][name16] Working => 1!!!
[c1][name16] Release.
[c1][name16] Wait.
[c1][name19] Begin.
[c1][name19] Working => 1!!!
```

Comment: So unexpected is that [c1][name1] prints 4 while [c1][name13] is still at 1?

Comment: In dotnet fiddle (with net5) its working fine. [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cFAk0n)

Comment: @Evk yes! always unexpected in specified debug mode.

Comment: @Martin if you run the code with netcore3.1 in visual studio 2019 community edition, and directly debug it, may have some problem.

Comment: @Jeffrey Hill: I see. Tried it out with dotnet core 2.1 there it is also working as expected (in VS). Just not with > 2.2

Comment: @JeffreyHill ... deleted my first answer. Like Evk described it very well sometimes it worked sometimes not :( starting with dotnet core so I expect this behaviour also in NET 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=netframework-4.7.1) of `Semaphore` (and `SemaphoreSlim`) of all versions, .NET core or not:

> There is no guaranteed order, such as FIFO or LIFO, in which blocked
> threads enter the semaphore.

In your example, suppose `[name1]` enters a semaphore, while all other threads waiting. `[name1]` prints 1 and increments counter. Then, *any* of the waiting threads can enter, in no particular order. Say it's `name2`. Meanwhile, `name1` is already blocked waiting on mutex. `name2` pritns 1, increments counter. Now key point - nothing prevents `name1` waiting on mutex to enter *again*, because no order is guaranteed. So it enters, prints 2, increments counter. Then name3 might enter, and after that name1 again, printing 3, while other threads are still at 1.

So "correct" behaviour you observe in full .net or without debugger is just happy coincidence, which is not guaranteed to happen. So when it does not happen - it's not a bug.

Comment: Thx, very nice document point. Even there is no guaranteed order, I also tested some output shows that it's unfair for some of those threads never been awaked and always starved(no count printed), Why does it happen?

Comment: @JeffreyHill for exactly the same reason: if there are multiple threads waiting on semaphore - any one of them can enter, in no particular order. So if there are always multiple threads waiting then it's possible some of them will never enter.

Comment: Your answer and explanation is so persuasive, but i am not sure about why builded executable or .net framework version makes all threads running evenly(i know unorderly is normal).

Comment: That's hard to say, because it depends on implementation details, so one has to dig into Semaphore source code to find out how it actually operates. It's intereseting of course, but not practical, because even if you will figure that out - you cannot rely on that anyway. Minor change in the next framework version (or running code on different operating system like linux, or even different linux flavours) and it can break again. Only documented features can be relied on. So best way is to consider this behavior as pure accident.